# Add list collection values to String to display in listview?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to take the values of a list and write them to a string that can be displayed in a listview. In my case I am retrieving a list of music releases that each have a list of artists.

Here is my class:

```
class DownloadsAvailable
{
    OAuth oAuth = new OAuth();
    public Metadata metadata { get; set; }
    public List<DownloadsAvailableResult> results { get; set; } // List of Songs
    public IEnumerator<DownloadsAvailableResult> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.results.GetEnumerator();
    }
}

public class DownloadsAvailableResult // Song
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public List<Artist> artists { get; set; }
    public string artistsList { get; set; } // New property to hold string list of artists
}
public class Artist
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string slug { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

And code behind

```
private async void GetDownloads()
    {
        OAuth oAuth = new OAuth();

        string oAuthVerifier = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["oauth_verifier"].ToString();
        string httpMethod = "GET";
        string parameters = "status=" + DownloadStatus.available.ToString();
        string response = await oAuth.GetData(OAuth.availDownloadsUrl, httpMethod, parameters, oAuthVerifier);
        DownloadsAvailable downloads = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DownloadsAvailable>(response);

        // Foreach loop here to enumerate over list of artists?

        this.listDownloads.ItemsSource = downloads;
    }
```

I'm not sure how to enumerate over the list of artists so i can join them into a single string that I can bind to a textblock within a listview.

Thanks for the help.

**UPDATE**
Thank you all for the answers, but i think i didn't explain my issue clearly. The data i get from web request returns a list of songs. Each song can have multiple artists. what i am trying to do is create a string of artists for EACH song. Then be able to bind that to a textblock in a listview.

Currently i've done this by nesting two listviews like so:

```
<ListView x:Name="listDownloads" ItemsSource="{Binding DownloadsAvailable}" SelectionChanged="listDownloads_SelectionChanged" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="auto">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image Source="{Binding images.large.url}" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,10,0,0" />
                            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="20,0,0,0">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}" Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemContentTextBlockStyle}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding release.name}" Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemSubheaderTextBlockStyle}"/>
                                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding artists}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" Margin="2"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                </ListBox>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

So instead of using a nested listbox to display the artists of a single song, i wanted to be able to a string of artists for each song and bind that to a textblock.

I hope this clears things up. Thanks.

Comment: So you are trying to get a list of `Artists` from your list of `DownloadsAvailableResult`?  Are you trying to turn a bunch of different `List<Artist>` into one string?

Comment: @ryanyuyu i'm trying to get the list of artists so i can do a string.join. that way i can display multiple artists as a comma separated string.

Comment: Ok.  Are you trying to do anything special, like remove duplicates?

Comment: you can use the `string.Join() method to delimit values in a list and have them stored in a string..

Comment: @ryanyuyu no i don't need anything special like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does something like this work for you?

```
string artistNames = string.Join(", ", 
    downloads.results.SelectMany(r => r.artists.Select(a => a.name)));
```

**UPDATE**

I didn't notice you had an `artistsList` property on your `DownloadsAvailableResult` class earlier. You might consider renaming it if it's only supposed to contain the artist names, and you can make it a read-only property by providing just a `get` method as follows:

```
public class DownloadsAvailableResult
{
    // Other properties here

    // Just return the names, don't allow this to be set by user 
    // (to add an artist name, add an Artist to the artists List)
    public string artistNames
    {
        get
        {
            return (artists == null)
                ? string.Empty // <-- or something like: "<No Artist Info Available>"
                : string.Join(", ", artists.Select(a => a.name));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Added an update to show how you can have a property on the class that returns the list of artists for each song in a single string.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATED

Based on your update, for each song, you want the list of artists for that song joined together into one string.  That is, you want one such string for every song (`DownloadsAvailableResult`) stored into a property.  This makes thing even simpler since every song already knows its own `List<Artist>`

```
foreach (var song in downloads.results)
{
   //Turn the list of artists into collection of names (strings)
   var artistNameCollection = song.artists.Select(artist => artist.name);

   //Assign to the property using String.Join to combine the collection
   song.artistsList = String.Join(", ", artistNameCollection);
}
```

Comment: While this works it grabs all artists from all of the songs. I need to be able to get the list of artists per song into a string. See my update.

Comment: @nos9 updated.  Hopefully this is more of what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The `String.Join` accepts an array of strings to be joined. Therefore create such an array from artists names:

```
public string artistsList {
    get {
        return String.Join(", ", artists.Select(a => a.name).ToArray());        
    }
}
```

Do you really want to have a setter? You can do so from a comma separated list of artists; however, the other properties of the artists will be missing.

```
    set {
        artists = value.Split(',')
            .Select(s => new Artist{ name = s.Trim() })
            .ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

here is an example - lets say that I have a List and the contents of that list are as follows

- valList[0] = "Status can not be empty"
- vlaList[1] = "This is is Test"

`declaration of the my List<T> variable`

```
var valList = new List<string>
{
   "Status can not be empty",
   "This is a Test"
};
var msgString = string.Join(", " , valList);
```

- The msgString would hold the following value - see below

`StatusCode can not be Empty, Service Requester Contract can not be Empty`